# loading gif for elapsed time

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

My page is loading late. I want to add loading gif in my page. There is a method that makes my page load late. I want the loading gif to stay for the time passed to this method or I want the loading gif to stay for 2 seconds.

my html coding like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>
  </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody *ngFor="let value of values">
   <tr>
    <td>{{value.id}}<td/>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

myvalues.component

```
 async getHomeValuesList () {
    const request: HomeValuesRequest = {
      userId: this.currentUser.userId,
      userName: this.currentUser.userName
    }
    const result = await this.ValuesMatchingService.homeValuesList(request);
    const response = result.data
    var descedingValues = response.ValuesModels.sort(function (a, b) {
      var dateA = new Date(a.valuesDate).getTime();
      var dateB = new Date(b.valuesDate).getTime();
      return dateA < dateB ? 1 : -1
    });
    descedingValues.forEach(data => {
      data.amountStr = data.amount.toLocaleString();
      this.values.push(data)
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this:

```
<img *ngIf="!values?.length || booleanvalue" src="assests/imgs/loading.gif" />
<table *ngIf="values?.length > 0 && !booleanvalue">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>
  </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody *ngFor="let value of values">
   <tr>
    <td>{{value.id}}<td/>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it worked but somewhere a boolean value is returning and different pages are opened according to the result, while this value is returning, my page loads late, in this case, what method should I try?
I tried *ngif="!booleanvalue" but it didn't work 
Is there anything like setting seconds?

Comment: yeah like this, I'll edit my answer

Comment: can you check it

Comment: can you mark it as a correct answer if it's work for you, hope it helps

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Now I looked again and neither worked. When I do !values.length the upload gif stays fixed if values == null. The same is true for the boolean value. values and boolean give late results. I want to put a gif until I get these results

Comment: can you share your ts code